# How to send an attachment from the main project

Tags: c#, botframework

This is a class from my code.

```
string to = message.Text;
string from = "noreply@zayzaycorporation.onmicrosoft.com";
MailMessage messagex = new MailMessage(from, to);

string mailbody = "Welcome!";
messagex.Subject = "Hello";
messagex.Body = mailbody;
messagex.Attachments.Add(new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("C:\\doc\\start.pdf"));

messagex.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
messagex.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com", 587);
System.Net.NetworkCredential basicCredential1 = new
                System.Net.NetworkCredential("noreply@zayzaycorporation.onmicrosoft.com", "XXX");
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = basicCredential1;

client.Send(messagex);
context.Done(string.Empty);
```

The class sends the email with an attachment, works good. But my problem is when it's published as a Web Service in azure because there doesn't find any folder named "doc" on "C:\\". How can it be referenced the attachment to a folder from the main solution? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [Attachment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ab7hb4y5(v=vs.110).aspx) class can be constructed using a `Stream`, which can thus contain anything and come from anywhere.

So basically generate the attachment in memory and wrap it in a `MemoryStream` or similar.

Comment: Works with that but can't open the file. The sent pdf size: 211KB, the pdf received: 312 bytes. Something happens.

Comment: I can't help you with that if you don't post the code for that question, please bear in mind that this is probably a *new* question though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

String path = Application.StartupPath + "\doc\test.xml";